# how to get the result if the pushed pageA is replaced by pageB

Tags: flutter, routes, navigator

The question is how to get the _parkSpace in the home page?

```dart
// in home page
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => FetchParkinglot(),
  ),
);
```

```dart
// in FetchParkinglot
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => BookRoute(l),
  ),
);
```

```dart
// in BookRoute
Navigator.pop(context, _parkSpace);
```

Comment: @pskink There is an asynchronous network request in FetchParkinglot. When the request is completed,  BookRoute will be pushed .  if pop BookRoute, the FetchParkinglot will send the network request again, so I can't do this, but I changed my code logic to avoid this problem: complete the network request in the main page and then enter the final page. sorry for my poor English

Comment: @pskink I want to use a transition page during the request

Answer (score 0):

```
 // in home page
  final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => FetchParkinglot(),
    ),
  );


  // in FetchParkinglot
  final result = await Navigator.push(//result is _parkSpace
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => BookRoute(l),
    ),
  );
  Navigator.pop(context,result);


  // in BookRoute
  Navigator.pop(context, _parkSpace);
```